# Run a Google App Engine on Travis-CI and test it with PhantomJS

Tags: google-app-engine, phantomjs, casperjs, travis-ci

Is there a way to run a Google App Engine [development appserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) instance on [Travis-CI](http://about.travis-ci.org/), and then test that app with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)/[CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)?

One would not necessarily expect this to be a tremendously challenging thing, but I would be grateful for any relevant document, thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

This was [discussed on Travis Github/issues](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/738), and in any case my solution has been to add this to `.travis.yml`:

```
before_script:
- wget https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.9.zip -nv
- unzip -q google_appengine_1.8.9.zip
```

I hope this helps.