# How do I have Travis-CI enter a password when prompted?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, travis-ci

I'm trying to have Travis-CI upload my GAE app to GAE after the tests succeed. I've figured that I have to:

1. Download GAE files (As shown in [Run a Google App Engine on Travis-CI and test it with PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114334/run-a-google-app-engine-on-travis-ci-and-test-it-with-phantomjs)) at `before_script`.
2. In the `after-script`, run `appcfg.py update`.

According to GAE's documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Uploading_the_App), though, it says that you cannot enter the password as a command-line option.

Is there a way I can configure Travis-CI to enter my password when prompted for it by `appcfg.py`? I am aware of Travis-CI's ability to store and pass secure environment variables (http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Secure-environment-variables)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instad of using user/password use the OAuth option and provide a token in your travis script.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed out that part of the documentation for some reason!