# Compile app engine in Travis ci and go

Tags: google-app-engine, travis-ci

Im trying to compile  this project [raygun4goGAE](https://github.com/miko-code/raygun4goGAE) on Travis ci.

But im getting  **cannot find package "appengine" in any of....**  its looks like the build cant find the appengine  dependencies?

I used this question [compile-app-engine-application-in-travis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614599/compile-app-engine-application-in-travis)  as a reference  how to creat the travis yaml file but i guess im missing something.

This is the yaml file :

```
language: go
go:
  - 1.2
  - 1.3
  - 1.4
  - tip
env:
  - GOARCH=386
  - GOARCH=amd64
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - go: tip
install:

  - export  FILE=$(curl https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/ | grep -o 'featured/go_appengine_sdk_linux_amd64-[^\<]*' | head -1)
  - curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/$FILE
  - unzip -q $FILE

  - go get github.com/smartystreets/goconvey
  - go get code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid
  - go get github.com/kaeuferportal/stack2struct
  - go get golang.org/x/net/context
  - go get google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch
  - go get google.golang.org/appengine

script:
    - ./go_appengine/goapp test ./tests;
    - ./go_appengine/goapp build ./raygun4goGAE;
```

And you can see [here](https://travis-ci.org/miko-code/raygun4goGAE) the Travis build result .

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to import google.golang.org/appengine instead

Comment: instead of "appengine"